# Is the following word choice correct?

Tags: word-choice

Is it possible to describe the relation between two countries as "negative" and "tepid"?

Are there any better alternatives usually used in media texts?

Comment: You'll have to narrow down the type of relation between them. Like positive /negative aspects, ties, etc.

Comment: It is negative. What I meant is whether those adjectives are usually used in such context or not. Would it sound weird to describe a relation as tepid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Tepid***, whch means "lukewarm" according to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tepid), has been used to describe relations between two countries.  For example, [The Christian Science Monitor](http://www.csmonitor.com/2003/0530/p12s01-uspo.html) in an article on May 30, 2003 describes a **cooling of relations** between the US and Russia as "**more tepid":**

> For US-Russia relations, a **more tepid** tête-à-tête
>
> No more 'goo-goo eyes,' but plenty to talk about as Bush and Putin
>   meet this weekend
>
> WASHINGTON AND MOSCOW — President Bush meets this weekend with Russian
>   President Vladimir Putin in the splendor of a refurbished St.
>   Petersburg. But all the gilt and exterior pastels of a czar's palace
>   won't be able to distract attention from the lost specialness and
>   mutual disappointments of US-Russia relations under the two leaders.
>
> Gone are the days of gazing into each others' souls and dancing the
>   cotton-eyed Joe in Texas hill country. In this post-Iraq-war reality,
>   neither side appears to feel the need to go too far in accommodating
>   the other...

Another article used **tepid** as **"not strong enough".**  See [Watching America](http://watchingamerica.com/WA/2011/01/29/the-new-g2s-disappointingly-tepid-pressure-on-north-korea/)  (The quote is the headline of an article in the Financial Times (South Korea) on 20 January 2011; G2 refers to the U.S. and China.)

> The New G2′s Disappointingly Tepid Pressure on North Korea

There is a very odd use of **tepid** in [Countering Terrorism and Insurgency in the 21st Century](https://books.google.com/books?id=MDXWDJocZBgC&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=relations+between+the+two+countries+were+tepid&source=bl&ots=6IH8Drt5B8&sig=9uCxyoj3mYqNYb5d-9IJdBbA9Mo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk0ovFn4_NAhWG9h4KHTwbA80Q6AEIHzAB#v=onepage&q=relations%20between%20the%20two%20countries%20were%20tepid&f=false)

> EVENTS LEADING UP TO THE COLE BOMBING
>
> Relations between the United States and the newly unified Yemen were **tepid** in the early 1990s ... By the mid-1990s, relations had begun to thaw between the two countries.....

The problem here is that tepid means lukewarm, and it is hard to see how something lukewarm can thaw, but that may be a physical scientist's quibble.

Finally, see [The History of Anglo-Japanese Relations 1600-2000: Volume IV](https://books.google.com/books?id=sGpaCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=relations+between+the+two+countries+were+tepid&source=bl&ots=LQFR9V3dm_&sig=Wu_0lskkOqSN_C-TM3cvmrZiYII&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk0ovFn4_NAhWG9h4KHTwbA80Q6AEINzAG#v=onepage&q=relations%20between%20the%20two%20countries%20were%20tepid&f=false), which describes a period when the interests of British and European manufacturers in the Japanese market were **tepid**.  From the context (page 83 second paragraph), it is clear that the author meant simply lukewarm -- that they weren't very interested.

For other examples, google  relations between the countries were tepid